# Updating text file using java

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I am doing an assignment and part of it I need to loop through a text file and output information depending on certain search terms which I have done, but after that I need to edit the document on one of the lines that the user would accept, my code to edit the document is:

```
int y = null;
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(fileName);
if (confirmation.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("What is your email to confirm your booking?");
                    email = S.next();

                    write.println(room + (" ") + roomB + (" ") + price + (" ") + pool + (" ") + lounge + (" ") + email);
                    y = 1;
                }
```

What happens after it finishes it will write just the one line and delete the rest of the data instead of just changing that one line.

Comment: i didn't get your problem, you try to change the entire content or just the line indicated ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am just trying to edit the one line, so say the line is "577 single 36.00 true true" I am trying to edit that line so it would result in "577 single 36.00 true true emailAddress" but keeping the rest of the document as is

Comment: If you know where to add text, you could try using [PrintWriter.Append()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that println() does not care about what you have in the file. It simply writes to the stream, resulting in overwriting your existing content.

If you need to change just one line consider reading the existing file content, then replacing the line in that content and then writing the whole modified content to the file.

Of course you have to remember that if the file is large it might get expensive or dangerous to read whole content at once so some optimisation may be required.